# Upload to azure file share using ansible without mounting

Tags: ansible, azure-files

I have an `azure storage account` in which i have a `azure file share`. Right now i am mounting it in a server and uploading the files there, is there a way in `ansible` that can extract and upload files directly to `azure share` instead of mounting that in a server and then doing the same? I have searched that in [azure_rm_storageaccount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_storageaccount_module.html), but could not get any idea other than `mounting`. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it. So what is the problem now?

Comment: Sorry, little busy.

Comment: Well, so does it solve the problem? Or something else?

Comment: i started using `azcopy`

Comment: OK, but I give the solution to the problem when you meet it, even if you do not use it anymore, you also need to reply and accept if it works. If you always ignore communities' help because of changing the way. Then you will end with no community help.

Comment: Only yesterday i started using it, i was really busy, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to upload the files directly through the module that Ansible provided. The special module does not exist currently. So you need to think out another way to achieve it through the Ansible.

For example, you can use the Azure CLI command [`azure storage file upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload) to upload the files to the Azure File Storage:

```
az storage file upload --account-key 00000000 --account-name MyStorageAccount --path path/file.txt --share-name MyShare --source /path/to/file
```

And then you can put this command in the ansible with [shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module) like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: Get all the access keys
    shell: aws iam list-access-keys --user-name {{ username }} --query 'AccessKeyMetadata[*].AccessKeyId'
```

Comment: Although this works, this will be really slow for upload and download. Better to use `azcopy`. Thanks. i have accepted this as answer anyways.

Comment: @doc_noob Yes, azcopy is quicker than this command, it's an Optimized tool, but there are also some pits. So use it carefully. And one answer to one question and it should respond and confirmed. That's the rules for SO.